# .htaccess mod_rewrite nor redirecting from "index" page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm creating site, where .htaccess file redirects main/index page (http://example.com, not http://example.com/index.html) to other page, that is rewrited to other page: (important for me is the first RewriteRule)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Index
RewriteRule ^$ /Page!Main_page[R]

# Pages
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[^!/]!
#RewriteRule ^(.*)(?!\?(.*))?$ /Page!$1?$2

# Pages with "!"
RewriteRule ^([^!]*)!([^!]*)$ /website.php/$2?section!$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: do you mean you need if some one request  site.com/main/index.php to be like site.com/inex.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with `!` in URL. I replaced it with `//` and it now works.